# Do I have to delete threads in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following function call from a thread:

```
        Thread Move = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                while(ButtonDown){
                    UpdateValues();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Move.start();
```

Will Android delete the thread when the while-loop breaks, or do I have to delete it in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return from the thread, you have essentially stopped it, so no, you don't need to do anything specific to delete the thread.  Please keep in mind that this is not a good use case for threads in Android.  If you are updating the UI from a non-UI thread you will most likely get the framework complaining at you.  Instead, you should read a few tutorials on AsyncTask and move to that model, as it *will* let you update the UI.

Comment: It is not doing any changes to the UI, it changes the values of some coordinates which gets handled by another thread which takes care of updating the screen by using lockcanvas. Is that an okay way to do it?

Comment: Sure, but you don't have to do anything to kill off the thread.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman do you know if it will be any difference with respect to performance?

Comment: no difference. runOnUiThread is simple, AsyncTask is more powerful. you just need to look at both and see which best fits what you need to do.

Answer (score 5):

There are two concepts here. One is the thread itself, the thing running in the processor, that has stack memory. The other is the `Thread` object, which is basically a control panel to access the thread.

The thread has stack memory which is released when the thread dies (`run()` completes or an exception is thrown, basically). However, the `Thread` java object stays around until there is no longer a reference to it.

So, let's say you had this:

```
this.myThread = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                int[] takeUpSomeMemory = new int[10000];

                while(ButtonDown){
                    UpdateValues();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
this.myThread.start();
```

So you have an instance variable `myThread` which holds a reference to a `Thread` you create. When the `start` method is called, your thread is called and it allocates quite a bit of memory for the variable `takeUpSomeMemory`. **Once the `run()` method dies by completing execution or throwing an exception the memory for `takeUpSomeMemory` is garbage collected.** The memory for `this.myThread` is retained until the instanceVariable is set to nil or the object of the enclosing class is garbage collected.